# Strange keyboard shortcuts and menu items

Tags: keyboard, language, shortcut-menu

I have just noticed that some items in the click-right menu and in the keyboard shortcuts settings are displayed in a different language now (Portuguese). The system default language is English and the OS is 10.6.8.

[image]

[image]

Why is this happening and how do I fix it?

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Can you redo the second screenshot but scroll up a bit to show the group title (like General)? You seem to have installed an extension but it's difficult to guess which one.

Comment: @patrix See the new screenshots that I’ve added.

Comment: Hmm, these seem to be standard services (I have them here as well), it's just that OS X seems confused about the system language for some of them. Strange indeed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This kind of localization glitch can often be fixed by going to system preferences/language & text/language and using the Edit button to uncheck the box for the offending language and then restarting.

Reports of this issue are not uncommon in the Apple forums.

Answer (score 0):

If you installed a Services plugin or a new app that provides services, it's probably that the app doesn't include English-language resources, or said resources got removed. Portuguese would be chosen as the display language if it's the topmost item in the list in `System Preferences -> Language & Text -> Language tab` that the app has resources for.

Comment: And how do I find the said app? Because I have no idea which one might be, and I don’t recall installing anything in a different language.

Comment: @Alex As patrix mentioned, they seem to be system services. Have you run anything like Monolingual recently?

Comment: No, nothing that I can remember of. However, see Tom’s answer—his solution worked for me.